# Adding table view in scroll view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am relatively new to iPhone development ,i tried to add uitableview to scroll view but it is showing Sigabart error then i added programatically and added uitableviewdelegate and uitableview data source to it and give delegate as self  and add 'noOfRowsInSection' method the delgate methods are not beeing called.can any one help me.

```
@interface Class : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {
     UITableView *table;
     UIScrollView *scrView;
     NSArray *array;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrView;
@end

here is my implementation

- (void)viewDidload
{
    array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"harsha",@"theja",@"pandu", nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 260, 360, 220)];
    [self.view addSubview:table];
    table.delegate = self ;


}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}

@end
```

I am adding the scroll view though Interface builder but i am doing table view progra matically the tabl view is shown on the screen but the methods are not beeing called

Comment: please show us the code & the delegate methods :) have you made the connection in interfacebuilder?
what is the error your console shows with the sigbart?

Comment: There are a large number of possible causes for this which are nearly impossible to debug without the code in question.

Comment: On a side note, UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. So if you need just standard vertical scrolling, just use a UITableView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st: you are using viewDidUnload instead of viewDidLoad,

2nd: add `tableview.dataSource = self` and implement the datasource delegate methods =)

you are using the delegate instead of the datasource =)

Comment: thank you i did it in view did load only but i havent added table.datasource to self.Adiing it resolved it.

Comment: sometimes its that simple =) 
glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

You are placing your code in the `viewDidUnload` method. Move this code to `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"harsha",@"theja",@"pandu", nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 260, 360, 220)];
    [self.view addSubview:table];
    table.delegate = self ;
}
```

**Should be this:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"harsha",@"theja",@"pandu", nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 260, 360, 220)];
    [self.view addSubview:table];
    table.delegate = self;
    table.dataSource = self;
}
```

Comment: i have done it in view did load only as you have asked the code ,in my application there are different other things to show to you i have created a class and pasted it in viewdidunload accidentally i am really sorry .

Comment: Thanks very much. [super viewDidUnload]; was marked as depreciate.